# Why isAnnotationPresent(Id.class) is not working for the class file

Tags: java, reflection, annotations

I have a class file `test.class`. In that file there is  annotations as `@Id` and `@Entity`. But when i check for the annotation with the method `field.isAnnotationPresent(Id.class)`, it returns `false`. I am getting all the fields in field variable.

Can any body tell me what mistake i did.

update:am using the following code to get the class

```
File file=new File("D:/test/");
URL url=file.toURL();
URL[] urls=new URL[]{url};
ClassLoader loader=new URLClassLoader(urls);
Class cls=loader.loadClass("com.net.test.Test");
```

Comment: Can you show us the code that is not working for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your test's classloader may have a different `Id` than `loader`'s.

A quick way to check:

```
...
Class idType = loader.loadClass("my.package.Id");
...
field.isAnnotationPresent(idType);
```

If that works, then you have a classloader problem -- more specifically, your `loader` does not use your test case's loader. To fix, use a different constructor:

```
ClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader(urls, this.getClass().getClassLoader());
```

Comment: you are right i changed the ClassLoader constructer.Now its working perfectly thank you very much.

Answer (score 36):

Have you annotated your annotation with a retention policy? If no retention policy is set the default retention policy behaviour is that the annotation is read by the compiler and also retained in the generated .class files but won't be accesible during runtime. If you need the annotation in runtime you need to annotate your annotations with:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
```

Comment: `@Id` and `@Entity` *do* have `RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME`

Comment: Thank you, I was missing the retentionpolicy in my code and was running in to similar problem.

Answer (score 2):

It works in general. Here's a working example:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class AnnotationTest {

    @Deprecated
    public static int value = 1;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Field field = AnnotationTest.class.getField("value");
        System.out.println(field.isAnnotationPresent(Deprecated.class));
    }
}
```

Double-check your classnames and imports. Maybe you accidentally check for a wrong `Id.class` (nameclash).

Answer (score 0):

If you use isAnnotationPresent() in Spring AOP interceptor and proxyTargetClass=false, add annotation on target interface instead of implementation class.